# Can I change pose of ArCore virtual camera or have multiple virtual cameras in a scene?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to apply offsets to both translation and rotation of ArCore's virtual camera pose(displayOrientedCameraPose). Is there any way I can do that ? ArCore's camera only lets me read the current pose and not edit/update the same. Trying to create another virtual camera that will have the Pose with offsets applied doesn't work since a frame can have only one camera.

Unlike many others I have started working with ArCore first with Unity and now moving to Android Studio. In Unity it was quite staright-forward since it supports multiple camera rendering. Wondering if anything similar is possible with Android Studio ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment ARCore allows you to use only one active ArSession which contains only one ArCamera, i.e. camera in your smartphone. Changing ArCamera's Pose is highly useless because 3D tracking heavily depends on its Pose (every ArFrame stores camera position and rotation as well as all scene's ArAnchors and feature points).

Instead of reposition and reorientation of your ArCamera you can move/rotate the whole ArScene.

Hope this helps.